# How to center align Zurb Foundation block grid elements that are being pushed to the next row?

Tags: html, sass, zurb-foundation

I'm using the block grid from the Zurb Foundation framework but I'm having some issues getting it to align the way I want to. I have it set so that it displays 4 blocks per row. I have more than 4 blocks so the ones that don't fit are pushed to the next row and aligned to the left. I want it so that those blocks are centered like this:

[image]

Is there a way to do that?

Here's what my code is looking like so far:

html

```
<ul class="small-block-grid-2 large-block-grid-4 thumbslist">
    {% for project in site.data.settings.projects %}
    <li>
    <a href="#" data-reveal-id="myModal{{ forloop.index }}" class="thumb-unit">
        <div class="thumb-overlay">
            <strong>{{ project.name }}</strong>
        </div>
        <div class="thumb" id="{{ project.folder }}" style="background-image: url(assets/img/{{ project.folder }}/thumb.png);"></div>
    </a>
    </li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

sass

```
.thumbslist
  margin: auto
  +clearfix

  li
    position: relative
    //display: inline-block
    display: block
    height: 200px 
    overflow: hidden
    padding: 0

 .thumb
    height: 100%
    width: 100%
    background-size: contain
    background-position: center center
    background-repeat: no-repeat
    padding: 0
```

Comment: Please post a working [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mJmMzP

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to make your list items not float so you can take advantage of `text-align: center` on the parent element:

```
.thumbslist
  margin: auto
  //+clearfix
  text-align: center // add

  li
    position: relative
    display: inline-block // add
    height: 200px 
    overflow: hidden
    padding: 5px
    float: none // add

  .thumb
    height: 100%
    width: 100%
    background-size: contain
    background-position: center center
    background-repeat: no-repeat
    padding: 0
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a modern browsers solution: Use flexbox for your layout and change to small-block-grid-3. Target CSS flex rules on <=991px.

```css
.thumbslist {
  margin: auto;
}
.thumbslist li {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 5px;
}
.thumbslist .thumb {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-size: contain;
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  padding: 0;
}
.thumbslist {
  margin: auto;
}
.thumbslist li {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 5px;
}
.thumbslist .thumb {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-size: contain;
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  padding: 0;
}
@media (max-width: 991px) {
  .thumbslist {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
    -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
    -webkit-justify-content: center;
    -ms-flex-pack: center;
    justify-content: center;
  }
}
```

```html
<ul class="small-block-grid-3 large-block-grid-4 thumbslist">
  <li>
    <div class="thumb" style="background: grey;"></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="thumb" style="background: grey;"></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="thumb" style="background: grey;"></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="thumb" style="background: grey;"></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="thumb" style="background: grey;"></div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

[**Codeply**](http://www.codeply.com/go/fQsgliFEg2)

Comment: There's no reason to use Flexbox for this at all.

Comment: I had to use this to produce the output screenshot he posted. Adding `text-align: center` did the same? I am not sure about it.